# Error when try to setup batch transform job

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [17] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [17] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (17)

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [17] [INFO] Using worker: gevent

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26

[2019-09-22 09:17:48 +0000] [30] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30

2019-09-22 09:18:15,061 INFO - sagemaker-containers - No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)

2019-09-22 09:18:15,062 INFO - sagemaker_sklearn_container.serving - Encountered an unexpected error.

[2019-09-22 09:18:15 +0000] [24] [ERROR] Error handling request /ping

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 56, in handle self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 160, in handle_request addr)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 107, in handle_request respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 119, in main user_module_transformer = import_module(serving_env.module_name, serving_env.module_dir)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 97, in import_module user_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/init.py", line 117, in import_module if name.startswith('.'):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

169.254.255.130 - - [22/Sep/2019:09:18:15 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 500 141 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"

2019-09-22 09:18:15,178 INFO - sagemaker-containers - No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)

2019-09-22 09:18:15,179 INFO - sagemaker_sklearn_container.serving - Encountered an unexpected error.

[2019-09-22 09:18:15 +0000] [30] [ERROR] Error handling request /ping

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 56, in handle self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 160, in handle_request addr)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 107, in handle_request respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 119, in main user_module_transformer = import_module(serving_env.module_name, serving_env.module_dir)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 97, in import_module user_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/init.py", line 117, in import_module if name.startswith('.')

here is the exact error , i am getting when i tired to setup a batch transform job

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be answer the question, please provide the code you are using to setup Batch Transform.